# Sitecore workflow quick action bar permissions

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have one workflow and two users with permissions to edit and publish.  When user1 edits an item, the item gets into the workflow and appears in user1's workbox.

The item doesn't appear in user2's workbox but in the quick action bar next to the item appears the state in the workflow and user2 can approve (run the available commands under that state) even though the item is locked by user1.

The workbox seems to behave as expected, display only items the user edits (in workflow).  But the quick action bar allows any user to run the commands available in the state the item is in even though the item is locked by someone else.

Both users belong to the same role, Author.

Any suggestions to get around this issue?

Thanks,

T

Comment: Your issue is that the quick action bar doesn't enforce ownership rights?

Comment: Yes, it should not allow a user to move the item to the next state in the workflow if the item is locked by another user.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the functionality of this icon by subclassing Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Gutters.WorkflowState:

```
public class SecureWorkflowGutterIcon : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Gutters.WorkflowState
{
    protected override Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Gutters.GutterIconDescriptor GetIconDescriptor(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Item.Locking.IsLocked() == false || 
            Sitecore.Context.Item.Locking.GetOwner() == Sitecore.Context.GetUserName())
        {
            return base.GetIconDescriptor(item);
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
```

This will render Workflow icons if they are not locked, or locked by the current user.

Next, go to the core database, and modify the item /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Gutters/WorkflowState, field Type, to refer to your new class: `YourNamspace.YourClass, YourAssembly`.